# Usar AsyncTask na captura de dados em pagina web em app Android

Tags: android, string, asynctask

Bom dia, mais um novato em desenvolvimento android. Indo direto ao ponto, gostaria de saber como chamar uma AsyncTask, que capte um String em uma pagina web, dentro de uma outra classe, passando a string captada para um TextField. Confesso que nao compreendi bem os exemplos encontrados, e gostaria de uma ajuda.
Desde já agradeço a qualquer um que responda a esse questionamento.

Comment: Rodolfo, seria bom se você postasse algum código do que já foi feito, assim seria mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: Rodolfo, bem vindo ao Stackoverflow! A sua pergunta é muito ampla para o formato do Stackoverflow. Veja como o site funciona na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Agradeço  as boas vindas. Rubico, desculpe a demora em responder a sua colocação.  Consegui resolver o problema relacionado a captura da String, mas estou com outro problema. Resumidamente, eu capto todo o Html da página, concateno-o em uma string e a envio para o TextView de outra activity. O problema é o seguinte: nao consigo tratar as letras acentuadas das.Por exemplo, se vou tratar a palavra "conexão", o metodo quebra a palavra em "conex" e "o". Como posso resolver este problema? PS: se a pergunta está  no lugar errado, por favor me orientem onde devo colocá-la.

Comment: Problema relacionado a caracteres especias resolvido.